# Service entrance wiring

Tags: wiring

Thanks for your help.
Is it possible for the meter on a detached garage be mounted on the outside wall and a through lug panel to be mounted on the interior wall of the garage which will also feed my 200 amp panel in the house.(New York State)
Lew

Comment: You apparently need to combine two accounts, https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts and register so you can edit your post, rather than asking the same question twice, slightly differently. Take the [tour]

Comment: I believe this is a follow up question, @Ecnerwal, not really a duplicate. Especially since it was asked in the "Answer" box on the OP's original question. Of course, it needs more detail, and it needs to be linked to the original question (starting with "thanks" for answering the other question doesn't help much), and it would be most helpful for the OP to register one of the accounts then [get the two of them combined](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)...